# Maximizing the Projection Size of Convex Shapes

Tags: geometry

The following question came up while considering the [lost in a forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%27s_lost_in_a_forest_problem) problem.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be convex. If $a$ is any $2$ dimensional vector, one can project $A$ in the direction of $a$ onto the line perpendicular to $a$. The projection will have a length $L$. We are only interested in the $a$ which maximizes $L$. Here is an example of $L$ being maximized when $A$ is a square.

[image: First diagram]

Suppose $A$ is translated some distance $v$ parallel to $a$ (recall $a$ maximizes $L$), and this process is repeated for the shape $A \cap (A + v)$. We can project $A \cap (A+v)$ in the direction $b$ onto the line perpendicular to $b$, yielding a length $L'$.

Trying this with various convex shapes, it always seems $L'$ is maximized when $b$ is parallel to $a$. Is this true?
[image: Diagram 2]